# Параллельное изменение громкости во всех вкладках

Tags: веб-программирование

Есть ресурс coub.com и я увидел интересную штуку:

Если открыть несколько видео с клипами на разных вкладках, то меняя звук на 1 вкладке, меняется звук на всех вкладках.

Как это работает? Разве вкладки браузера не изолированы между собой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это реализовано через [LocalStorage](https://ustimov.org/posts/16/):

> LocalStorage представляет собой постоянное хранилище данных,
>   расположенное у пользователя на локальном диске. Таким образом, в нём
>   можно сохранять данные, которые будут доступны веб-приложению даже
>   если пользователь перейдёт на другую страницу сайта, либо даже вовсе
>   покинет страницу и зайдёт через некоторое время.

Т.е. сайт работает с одним и тем же хранилищем, неважно сколько вкладок вы откроете.
В случае с coub.com громкость плеера храниться по ключу `player_sound_level`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]